# Pulling out the "cell" values using SED from an RTF file

Tags: sed

How can I extract the "cell" information from an RTF file using SED (bash shell). ie all the character strings between any pairs of { }, of which there can be several on a line of RTF. I want to strip out all the RTF code and just keep the table values.

Comment: awk is better at this kind of thing, I believe... better at working with delimiters.

Comment: How do you want to handle plain text outside of tables?  If you only want the text within a table, that's going to be considerably harder.

Comment: Maybe you should show what you've got in your RTF file.  I created a simple RTF file and the `{}` marks are not around items in table cells.  Granted, this was RTF created on a Mac, not on a Windows machine.  Also, do you want the `{}` markers kept or not?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/{/!d;s/[^{]*{\([^}]*\)}/\1\n/;P;D' file
```

It deletes any line that does not have an opening brace. Then removes any characters upto and including the first opening brace. Then prints the string(s) within but not including the closing brace on a separate line.

Comment: The RTF file is from a Word Table. I am looking to capture only the values within the table cells and place them into a plain text file. There can be multiple sets of { } in the same line due to multiple columns in the Word table. It would also be useful to capture all cases of {N=xx} where xx is a number. Thank you very much for your help.